# Помогите слить массивы через php

Tags: php, массивы

Как с помощью php объединить эти 2 массива

во втором массиве lang_id ссылается на первый массив

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => ru
        [created] => 1539766312218
        [name] => Русский
        [id] => 1
        [ownerId] => 
        [updated] => 1539766392838
        [objectId] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
        [___class] => langs
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => de
        [created] => 1539766491804
        [name] => Deutsch
        [id] => 2
        [ownerId] => 
        [updated] => 1539766532679
        [objectId] => 79F70774-58BB-7D1C-FF4A-783DABF25C00
        [___class] => langs
    )

)


 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [created] => 1539766406514
        [lang_id] => 1
        [listorder] => 1
        [id] => 1
        [ownerId] => 
        [word] => man
        [updated] => 1539766423895
        [objectId] => 08F5A487-7649-BB93-FFC0-83C4F37BB500
        [translate] => Человек
        [___class] => lang_values
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created] => 1539766435042
        [lang_id] => 2
        [listorder] => 1
        [id] => 2
        [ownerId] => 
        [word] => man
        [updated] => 1539766475856
        [objectId] => 6F728A08-0038-6763-FFB6-E87B96075500
        [translate] => ein Mann
        [___class] => lang_values
    )

)
```

чтоб было так

```
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [code] => ru
        [created] => 1539766312218
        [name] => Русский
        [id] => 1
        [ownerId] => 
        [updated] => 1539766392838
        [objectId] => 0E5BD427-7883-903C-FFDD-2309E2D79800
        [___class] => langs

        [0] => Array
    (
        [created] => 1539766406514
        [listorder] => 1
        [id] => 1
        [ownerId] => 
        [word] => man
        [updated] => 1539766423895
        [objectId] => 08F5A487-7649-BB93-FFC0-83C4F37BB500
        [translate] => Человек
        [___class] => lang_values
        )
        .....и так далее все значения языка..
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => de
        [created] => 1539766491804
        [name] => Deutsch
        [id] => 2
        [ownerId] => 
        [updated] => 1539766532679
        [objectId] => 79F70774-58BB-7D1C-FF4A-783DABF25C00
        [___class] => langs

            [0] => Array  (
            [created] => 1539766435042
            [listorder] => 1
            [ownerId] => 
            [word] => man
            [updated] => 1539766475856
            [objectId] => 6F728A08-0038-6763-FFB6-E87B96075500
            [translate] => ein Mann
            [___class] => lang_values
            )

            .....и так далее все значения языка..

    )

 )
```

Comment: преобразуйте первый массив так, чтобы ключом был `id`. в этом вам поможет `array_combine()`  и `array_column`. а потом добавляйте элементы из второго к первому по `lang_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый массив назвал $langs, второй $array:

```
foreach ($langs as $key => $lang) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($lang['id'] == $item['lang_id']) {
            $langs[$key]['property'] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чуть переделал, но пригодилось, спасибо Вам огромное!